# Split Up Recipients names to get first names

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to break up the full name of two Recipients to get the first names.

Here is the code:

```
For r = 1 To .recipients.Count
    Debug.Print .recipients(r)
    strgreetname = Left(.recipients(r), InStr(1, .recipients(r), " ") - 1)
    strTo = Left(strGreetNameAll, InStr(1, .recipients(r), " ") - 2)
    strGreetNameAll = strGreetNameAll & strgreetname & ", "
    strgreetnameall1 = strgreetname
Next r

For i = 1 To .recipients.Count
    Debug.Print .recipients(i)
    strgreetname = Left(.recipients(i), InStr(1, .recipients(i), " ") - 1)
    strTo1 = Right(strTo, InStr(1, .recipients(i), " ") - 2)
    strGreetNameAll = strGreetNameAll & strgreetname & ", "
    strgreetnameall1 = strgreetname
Next i
```

I cannot get `strTo` and `strTo1` to work separately based on the recipients count.  It seems to only change if I change the first defined item, in this case `r`.  Changing the `i` value does nothing.  It seems that the first defined variable controls everything below it, even though I have it set separately.  How do I break these up so that `r` controls one section, while `i` controls another, so they work autonomously?

Update--I got it to separate but the first alias (strTO) is cutting off in strange ways.  I want to cut off at the first space in the alias, which I thought I did with the "left" piece.  However, it is not consistent, cutting off long names, or pulling in parts of the next name if the first alias was a short name (like Tom).

```
For R = 1 To .recipients.Count
    Debug.Print .recipients(R)
    strgreetname = Left(.recipients(R), InStr(1, .recipients(R), " "))
    strgreetname2 = Left(.recipients(2), InStr(1, .recipients(R), " "))
    strGreetNameAll = strGreetNameAll & strgreetname
    strGreetNameAll1 = strgreetname
    strTo = Left(strGreetNameAll, InStr(1, .recipients(R), " "))
    strTo1 = Left(strgreetname2, InStr(1, .recipients(R), " "))
Next R
```

StrTO and strTO1 are the first and second aliases in the To field, respectively.

For example:
Given .Recipients "William Hartnell", "Carole Ann Ford", "Patrick Troughton", "Anneke Wills", "Jon Pertwee", and "Tom Baker".

I want strTO to be William. I want strTO1 to be Carole. So it could be Dear William and Carole.

Comment: I've got no idea what you are trying to achieve (maybe some data examples would help) but the line saying `strTo1 = Right(strTo, InStr(1, .recipients(i), " ") - 2)` seems wrong - it is looking for a space in `.recipients(i)` and then using that to take a certain part of `strTo`, which has been set based on where the first space occurred in `recipients(recipients.Count)`.

Comment: Unsure what you try to achieve with 2 different loops to do something very similar. In your `For i` loop, you used `strTo` which is the last value from `For r` loop, is that what your "control" issue?

Comment: Hello, let me further explain what I am doing. I don't need all the extra in the second grouping as was pointed out, the only one I need there is the strTo1. I'm trying to separate the recipients in the TO field in a reply. This method has worked, with the strTO being the 1stperson, the strTO1 being the 2nd person in the string.  If r=1, it pulls the 1st name of the 1st alias. If r=2, the 2nd.  If set to 3, the 3rd alias.  I need them to work separately, so it pulls BOTH the 1st and 2nd aliases. So r controls 1st name, i controls 2nd.  Right NOW, r controls both.  Trying to separate i and r.

Comment: Please see my latest update in original question.  Need now to get it to cut the names at the first space, so as to pull only the first name.

Comment: Assuming your original `.Recipients` were `"William Hartnell"`, `"Carole Ann Ford"`, `"Patrick Troughton"`, `"Anneke Wills"`, `"Jon Pertwee"`, and `"Tom Baker"`, what do you want `strTO` to end up being, and what do you want `strTO1` to end up being?

Comment: I want strTO to be Wiliam.  I want strTO1 to be Carole.  So it could be Dear William and Carole.  Thanks for the follow-up, I know you guys have better things to do.

Comment: The site is set up for one question at a time. Note you will not be able to accept a second answer. You can delete the extra question and start a new one. Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve so information does not have to be beaten out of you.

Comment: Oh hey Niton, nice to see you!  Thanks, I just read that and will post the question anew and will link it back here.  I will try to make it verifiable and complete!

Comment: Okay, I posted my new question, I hope it is clear and concise this time!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46351976/outlook-vba-insert-item-into-text-body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment that you want `strTO` to be all characters up to the first space in `.Recipients(1)`, and you want `strTO1` to be all characters up to the first space in `.Recipients(2)`, then you can use the following code:

```
strTO = Left(.Recipients(1), InStr(.Recipients(1) & " ", " ") - 1)
If .Recipients.Count > 1 Then
    strTO1 = Left(.Recipients(2), InStr(.Recipients(2) & " ", " ") - 1)
Else
    strTO1 = ""
End If
```

---

And, if you were using this to create a "greeting", you could just use something like:

```
strGreetName = Left(.Recipients(1), InStr(.Recipients(1) & " ", " ") - 1)

If .Recipients.Count > 1 Then
    strGreetName = strGreetName & " and " & Left(.Recipients(2), InStr(.Recipients(2) & " ", " ") - 1)
End If
```

and not worry about having `strTO` and `strTO1`.

---

Or, if you wanted to include **all** the names, you could use something like

```
strGreetName = ""
For i = 1 to .Recipients.Count
    If i > 1 Then
        If i = .Recipients.Count Then
            strGreetName = strGreetName & " and "
        Else
            strGreetName = strGreetName & ", "
        End If
    End If
    strGreetName = strGreetName & Left(.Recipients(i), InStr(.Recipients(i) & " ", " ") - 1)
Next
```

Comment: Wow, wow, wow Yow, you are stupendous!!  Holy schneikes, it worked!!  It really worked!!  Thank you so much!  I knew I would find the people with the answers here.  I see what you did, and had no idea I needed that extra space in the defining of strTo.  Worked perfectly.  Here is my next question, now that we have defined the items (strTO and strTO1), can they be entered into the body text?  I am putting that in my question above with the code I have currently for that, or should I ask that as a separate question?  Thank you again so much!

Comment: I do not know how to thank you technically on here, or add to your rep....

Comment: @learningthisstuff The extra space I added when doing the `InStr` (i.e. `.Recipients(i) & " "`) is simply there to **ensure** that there is a space to be found.  E.g. if the string you were looking at simply had a single name in it (e.g. `"John"`), then `Instr(.Recipients(i), " ")` would return 0 and it would then try to find the leftmost **-1** characters of `"John"` and crash.

Comment: @learningthisstuff Thanking people for assistance (and adding to their rep) is done by "accepting" the answer, which you have already done.  Once you get enough rep of your own, you can also upvote answers (on your questions and any other question) that you believe add value, even when they aren't necessarily **the** answer that the person asking the question got the most value from.

Comment: Okay yeah, I tried upvote but have no rep, so could not.  Let me ask you another question on this piece Yow.  When there is more than one sender in the To, the code works awesome.  If only ONE person, it errors out with an 'array out of bounds'.  But your code has Else, "".  So shouldn't it run, but just have it be blank for the strTO1?

Comment: @learningthisstuff That's why I put the test for `.Recipients.Count` in there for, so that it would only look at `.Recipients(2)` if there were more than one recipient.  (I know that it will crash on `strTO = Left(.Recipients(1), InStr(.Recipients(1) & " ", " ") - 1)` if there are **no** recipients, but I'm hoping you are always having at least one recipient.)  I assume the line it is crashing on is `strTO1 = Left(.Recipients(2), InStr(.Recipients(2) & " ", " ") - 1)`?

Comment: Another aha! moment for me, you are right yet again!  I fixed it up.  =)

Answer (score 0):

you are doing this

```
for r = 1 to 10
    a = r + 4
next r

for i = 1 to 10
    b = a + 2
next r
```

when you want

```
for r = 1 to 10
    a = r + 4
    b = a + 2
next r
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried that.  The reason I need them separate is b/c I am trying to pull two separate items, the 1st and 2nd aliases from the TO field when creating a reply.  The key focus is strTO and strTO1, representing the 1st and 2nd alias.  I need it to pull based on the recipients count, so r=1 pulls 1st.  r=2 pulls 2nd.  I want to pull BOTH, so need to have r=1, then, separately, i=2.  Right now, r is changing both sections, whereas I need them to work autonomously, so that i can change strTO1 on its own, while r changes srtTO.  Do you know how I can achieve that?  Thank you!!

Comment: Thank you, I took your advice, see my update above!  I am now just trying to get the first name in the aliases to pull correctly.  So Tom Jones would become Tom.  Severus Snape would become Severus.  Thanks again!